# Finding maximum combination of keys that share the same value

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(
 key NUMBER(5), 
 val NUMBER(5)
 );

insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,1);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,2);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,3);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (2,3);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,4);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (2,4); 
insert into ABC (key, val) values (2,5);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (3,5);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,6);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (2,6);
```

**Desired Output:**
[image]

I want to find the maximum pairs of keys that share the same value, and list them, in the above example the maximum pairs of keys that occur in the table are (1,2) which share values (3,4,6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use self join and analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.key, tt.key as key1, t.val,
        Count(distinct val) over (partition by t.key, tt.key) as cnt
  From your_table t join your_table tt
    On t.val = tt.val and t.key < tt.key)
Order by cnt desc 
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

In oracle 11g, fetch clause is not supported. So you should use `dense_rank` as follows:

```
select key, key1, val from
(select key, key1, val, 
dense_rank() over (order by cnt desc) as dr  from(
Select a.key, b.key as key1, a.val,
        Count(distinct a.val) over (partition by a.key, b.key) as cnt
  From abc a join abc b
    On a.val = b.val and a.key < b.key) )
    where dr = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40106f/15

Comment: Hi Popeye, The last line of the code give me an error, I have attached a link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40106f/11

Comment: You are getting error as fetch clause is introduced in oracle 12c

Answer (score 2):

Please try as below:

```
select ab,val from (
select rank() over( order by cnt desc) rn, ab, val ,cnt
from (
select listagg(key,',')  within group(order by val) ab,val, 
count(1) over (partition by (listagg(key,',')  within group(order by val))) cnt
from abc
group by val
having count(*) > 1))
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep Garg, Is there a way to get it without the listagg?

Comment: @StackOne, I used listagg because i am not sure if number of keys will be constant. It can be combination of 3 keys also

Comment: It has to be the maximum pairs, In my example 1,2 has the maximum pairs. there is 1 pair for 2,3 and 0 pairs for 1,3

Comment: I am trying to say if there is below data:0 insert into ABC (key, val) values (3,3);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (3,6);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (3,4); so 3 keys (1,2,3) will have maximum rows. That I am asking if there will always 2 keys or number of keys can be different

Comment: Yes, in that case the output should display (key,key1,key2,val) (1,2,3,3 ) (1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,6)

Comment: @StackOne - because number of column are dynamic, thats why i used listagg.